# SQL server replication error: "The initial snapshot for publication 'XYZ' is not yet available"

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication

I am using sql server 2012, and i've set up a snapshot replication between two servers. The snapshot agent completed successfully, however the replication agent seems keep running forever and cannot stop.

The action message from replication monitor is like:

> Initializing
>   Applied Script 'ScriptX.pre'
>   ...
>   Bulk copied data into table 'tabA'
>   ...
>   Delivered snapshot from the 'replicaDataSubFolder' sub-folder in x milliseconds
>   **The initial snapshot for publication 'XYZ' is not yet available.**

And then the action message stuck at the last sentence and cannot stop.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The message ***The initial snapshot for publication 'XYZ' is not yet available*** was most likely a transient message which popped because the Snapshot Agent had not finished generating the snapshot yet.

After the snapshot was generated, the Distribution Agent began applying the snapshot, which is why you then saw the messages ***Delivered snapshot from the 'replicaDataSubFolder' sub-folder in x milliseconds ..... Bulk copied data into table 'tabA'***.

This is normal and by design.

Verify the snapshot was successfully applied at the subscriber.  You can do this by examining the data at the subscriber.

Comment: Hi Brandon,please see my updated action message, this 'The initial snapshot...' message is the last action message. And before the distribution agent runs, the snapshot agent already completed successfully.

Comment: Are you running the Distribution Agent continuously?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean 'continuously', i triggered the agent job manually.

Comment: If you right-click the Distribution Agent job underneath SQL Server Agent -> Jobs -> Properties and navigate to the Steps page, and click Edit, does the Command text contain the -Continuous parameter?

Comment: Yes, it has Continuous parameter.

Comment: I believe this is by design.  Does the data get replicated successfully?

Comment: You mean if the continuous parameter is set, it will never stop? the subscriber has, at least, partial of the replicated data, but how can i verify that all the data is consistent?

Comment: Tablediff utility or SQL Data Compare.

Comment: Thanks, I've verified and this should be by design

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://systemcenter.wiki/?GetElement=Microsoft.SQLServer.2000.The_initial_snapshot_for_article_is_not_yet_available&Type=Rule&ManagementPack=Microsoft.SQLServer.2000.Monitoring&Version=6.0.6648.0) solved my problem.

Causes:

You have created or reinitialized a transactional subscription that was created with the Yes, initialize the schema and data option, and you started the Distribution Agent before you started the Snapshot Agent or before the Snapshot Agent had completed. You will only see this error if there is only one article associated with the Distribution Agent. If there are multiple articles associated with the the Distribution Agent, you may see the error 21075, "The initial snapshot for publication '%s' is not yet available."

Solution:

If the associated Snapshot Agent has not been started since the subscription was created or if it has not been started since the last time you choose to reinitialize the subscription, you will need to start the Snapshot Agent and let it complete before starting the Distribution Agent.

If the Snapshot Agent does not complete, check the Snapshot Agent history for errors and address them. If necessary, you can add a log to the Snapshot Agent to see if more details can be returned for any errors.